# As a revert, how do I stop losing my imaan when my duas are not answered?

Tags: allah, dua, imaan

I'm a revert from christianity, and I have been just trying to test out other religions and Islam is the one that stuck out to me even when I went back to Christianity.

I saw that Islam really affected me in a good way. But every time I try to fully embrace islam I lose motivation, and I don't know what I have to do.

I have faith in Allah SWT but I ask for help from Him and nothing happens and over time this has led me to just overall give up.

How do I stop losing my imaan when my duas are not answered?

Answer (score 2):

Surround yourself with those who can strengthen your emaan.

> The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “A man is upon the
> religion of his best friend, so let one of you look at whom he
> befriends.”
>
> Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2378

Comment: this is excellent advice

Answer (score 1):

### Do not loose faith - Allah has heard your dua, but may not answer it as you expect

I'm going to quote an older translation of the Qu'ran, as it makes clearer your situation:

> And when My servants question thee concerning Me, then surely I am nigh. I answer the prayer of the suppliant when he crieth unto Me. So let them hear My call and let them trust in Me, in order that they may be led arigh
> — [Quran 2:186](https://quran.com/2?startingVerse=186&translations=19)

The translation I am familiar with is 'The caller when he calls'. In short, you do not need to be Muslim to call to Allah nor to be answered!

> We verily created man and We know what his soul whispereth to him, and We are nearer to him than his jugular vein.
> — [Quran 50:16](https://quran.com/50?startingVerse=16)

Even if it is your soul whispering to you, Allah is aware of it.

---

So why does it feel like your cries for help are not answered?

> I ask for help from Him and nothing happens

However, you do not know how Allah plans to answer your prayer.

> Abu Sa’id al-Khudri reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, "There is no Muslim who calls upon Allah, without sin or cutting family ties, but that Allah will give him one of three answers: He will quickly fulfill his supplication, He will store it for him in the Hereafter, or He will divert an evil from him similar to it." They said, "In that case we will ask for more." The Prophet said, "Allah has even more."
>
> Source: Musnad Aḥmad 11133
> — retrieved from [Daily Hadith online](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2016/05/25/supplication-answered-three-ways/)

It is possible that Allah is storing your duas up as reward for the hereafter, or that He will divert a greater evil from you. I have heard 'divert a greater evil' translated/interpreted as 'provide something better', but I cannot source that.

For instance, you make dua for a Job but Allah know that job won't be halal, or will cause you to become sinful, so by diverting you from that He will provide something better.

Here is a good [article on IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5113/why-doesnt-allaah-answer-our-duaas) with good advice on how to make good duas that will be answered, some of which may have not been immediately obvious as a revert (I have found this as a revert myself).

---

In terms of keeping your imaan high, I recommend reading the Qu'ran (or a translation if necessary) regularly, attending Jummah prayer (in English if you do not speak arabic yet), and surrounding yourself with other Muslims, as [Riaz's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/76037/43) suggests. None of these will feel like they come naturally, because as a revert you have not been doing this as long as non-reverts but once you get into the habit you'll start seeing the benefits.